# How do I efficiently keep track of the smallest element in a collection?

Tags: data-structures, collections

In the vein of *programming questions*: suppose there's a collection of objects that can be compared to each other and sorted. What's the most efficient way to keep track of the smallest element in the collection as objects are added and the current smallest occasionally removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a min-heap is the best way.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)

It is tailor made for this application.

Comment: A fibonacci heap is faster than min-heap, it has O(1) insertion instead of O(log(n))

Comment: I've never heard of a Fibonacci Heap

Comment: [this was originally a separate 'answer' that I posted before comments were implemented] That was my initial suggestion until I realized that min-heaps weren't designed for random removal of elements, only the smallest one.

Well whatever, it looks like your answer was accepted anyways.

Answer (score 1):

If you need random insert and removal, the best way is probably a sorted array. Inserts and removals should be O(log(n)).

Answer (score 1):

@Harpreet
That is not optimal.  When an object is removed, erickson will have to scan entire collection to find the new smallest.

You want to read up on [Binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)'s.  MS has a good [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336800.aspx) to start down the path.  But you may want to get a book like [Introduction to algorithms (Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937) if you want to deep dive.

Answer (score 1):

For occasional removes a [Fibonacci Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) is even faster than the min-heap. Insertion is O(1), and finding the min is also O(1). Removal is O(log(n))

Answer (score 0):

> If you need random insert and removal,
>   the best way is probably a sorted
>   array. Inserts and removals should be
>   O(log(n)).

Yes, but you will need to re-sort on each insert and (maybe) each deletion, which, as you stated, is O(log(n)).

With the solution proposed by Harpreet:

- you have one O(n) pass in the beginning to find the smallest element
- inserts are O(1) thereafter (only 1 comparison needed to the already-known smallest element)
- deletes will be O(n) because you will need to re-find the smallest element (keep in mind Big O notation is worst case).  You could also optimize by checking to see if the element to be deleted is the (known) smallest, and if not, just don't do any of the re-check to find the smallest element.

So, it depends.  One of these algorithms will be better for an insert-heavy use case with few deletes, but the other is overall more consistent.  I think I would default to Harpreet's mechanism unless I knew that the smallest number would be removed often, because that exposes a weak point in that algorithm.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that big-O is not necessarily worst-case.. it's just a notation for describing asymptotic behavior of functions, it doesn't "know" anything about worst-case or best-case or anything in between, it's just for describing the behavior of whatever function you're looking at.

Comment: In fact, I'd go so far as to say that unless it's specified, big-O notation is used most often to describe the average case, not the worst-case.

Answer (score 0):

Harpreet:

> the inserts into that would be linear since you have to move items for an insert.

Doesn't that depend on the implementation of the collection?  If it acts like a linked-list, inserts would be O(1), while if it were implemented like an array it would be linear, as you stated.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which operations you need your container to support.  A [min-heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) is the best if you might need to remove the min element at any given time, although several operations are nontrivial (amortized log(n) time in some cases).

However, if you only need to push/pop from the front/back, you can just use a mindeque which achieves amortized constant time for all operations (including findmin).  You can do [a scholar.google.com search](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=mindeque) to learn more about this structure.  A friend and I recently collaborated to reach a much easier-to-understand and -to-implement version of a mindeque, as well.  If this is what you're looking for I could post the details for you.